# Getting exception while reading data from blob in azure

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

While I am trying to read the list of blob data on azure, I am getting the following error:

Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link. Your code likely has a endless loop. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234762.aspx